# Solution to a 2D Schrödinger equation

Tags: differential-equations, physics, boundary-conditions, wave-propagation

I am trying to solve a 2D Schrödinger equation with a complicated non-separable potential $V(z,\rho)$,

$$ \nabla^{2}\Psi(z,\rho) +2(E_{0}-V(z,\rho))\Psi(z,\rho),$$

where $E_{0}$is the energy, $\hbar=m=0$, and the $z$ and $\rho$ are Cartesian coordinates-just to keep the names consistent with my script.

(Edit)
We can write the quantity $2(E_{0}-V(z,\rho))$ as $k^{2}$, where the $k$ is a wave vector.

In my setup a plane wave impinges at an arbitrary angle with momentum $k$ and I want to calculate the reflectivity, thus my first step is to solve a 2D pde, and this step is proving difficult.

As means of de-bugging I have simplified my problem quite a bit to look for possible issues, that is, I made the potential one-dimensional i.e., $V(z)$ and I am shooting the plane wave along $z$, but I am still trying to solve a 2D problem.

$$ \nabla^{2}\Psi(z,\rho) +2(E_{0}-V(z))\Psi(z,\rho),$$

What I would be expecting from the solution is the invariance in the $\rho$ direction but the solution varies in both $z$ and $\rho$

```
(* domain and constants*)

zMin = 0.1;
zMax = 10;
\[Rho]Min = -10;
\[Rho]Max = 10;
\[Theta]0 = 0;

(*Energy*)
E0 = 0.65;

(* one-dimensional potential*)
V[z_] := - (1/(z + 0.1)^2)

(*direction of propagation*)
kn[\[Theta]_] := Normalize[{1, Tan[\[Theta]]}];

(*k-vector*)
kVectorT[\[Theta]_, z_] := Sqrt[2 (E0 - V[z] )]*kn[\[Theta]]

(*Schrodinger equation*)
eqnT = {Laplacian[u[z, \[Rho]], {z, \[Rho]}] + 
    kVectorT[\[Theta]0, z] . kVectorT[\[Theta]0, z]* u[z, \[Rho]] == 
   0};

(*boundary conditions*)
bcT = {u[z, \[Rho]Min] == 
   Exp[-I kVectorT[\[Theta]0, z] . {z, \[Rho]Min}], 
  u[z, \[Rho]Max] == Exp[-I kVectorT[\[Theta]0, z] . {z, \[Rho]Max}],
   u[zMin, \[Rho]] == 
   Exp[-I kVectorT[\[Theta]0, zMin] . {zMin, \[Rho]}] , 
  u[zMax, \[Rho]] == 
   Exp[-I kVectorT[\[Theta]0, zMax] . {zMax, \[Rho]}]};

(*solution*)
solT = NDSolve[{eqnT, bcT}, 
  u, {z, zMin, zMax}, {\[Rho], \[Rho]Min, \[Rho]Max}, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}];

(*Plots*)
lineT = ParametricPlot3D[{z, \[Rho], 
    Abs[u[z, \[Rho]] /. solT]} /. {z -> t , \[Rho] -> 
     Tan[\[Theta]0] t}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];

surfaceT = 
 Plot3D[Abs[u[z, \[Rho]] /. solT], {z, zMin, 
   zMax}, {\[Rho], \[Rho]Min, \[Rho]Max}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "\[Rho]"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];

Show[surfaceT, lineT]
```

[image: 3d plot of the solution]

if I solve it without the potential I do get a nice plane wave

```
kVectorN[\[Theta]_, z_] := Sqrt[2 (E0 )]*kn[\[Theta]]
eqnN = {Laplacian[u[z, \[Rho]], {z, \[Rho]}] + 
     kVectorN[\[Theta]0, z] . kVectorN[\[Theta]0, z]* u[z, \[Rho]] == 
    0};
bcN = {u[z, \[Rho]Min] == 
    Exp[-I kVectorN[\[Theta]0, z] . {z, \[Rho]Min}], 
   u[z, \[Rho]Max] == Exp[-I kVectorN[\[Theta]0, z] . {z, \[Rho]Max}],
    u[zMin, \[Rho]] == 
    Exp[-I kVectorN[\[Theta]0, zMin] . {zMin, \[Rho]}] , 
   u[zMax, \[Rho]] == 
    Exp[-I kVectorN[\[Theta]0, zMax] . {zMax, \[Rho]}]};
solN = NDSolve[{eqnN, bcN}, 
   u, {z, zMin, zMax}, {\[Rho], \[Rho]Min, \[Rho]Max}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}];

surfaceN = 
  Plot3D[Re[u[z, \[Rho]] /. solN], {z, zMin, 
    zMax}, {\[Rho], \[Rho]Min, \[Rho]Max}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"z", "\[Rho]"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];

lineN = ParametricPlot3D[{z, \[Rho], 
     Abs[u[z, \[Rho]] /. solN]} /. {z -> t , \[Rho] -> 
      Tan[\[Theta]0] t}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];

Show[surfaceN, lineN]
```

[image: Plane wave solution]

**Question**

Have I set the boundary conditions properly? In my full 2D problem I am shooting the plane wave at a grazing incidence thus I can't say that $k \approx \sqrt(2 E_{0})$ at the boundaries close to the $z\approx 0$

**EDIT**

I realised that the boundary conditions are definitely wrong as the solution at the boundaries needs to be a linear combination of the wave going in and the reflected one. Is there a way of simplifying the boundary conditions?
**EDIT 2**

I am not really sure how to tackle the boundary conditions in two dimensions.

For a 1D problem for a wave impinging from the right the boundary condition at infinity is  $\exp(- i k(x)x) + B \exp(i k(x)x)$, where $B$ is the amplitude of the reflected wave and far enough to the right we can assume that the effects of the potential are negligible so $k(x)$ there is just $k = E_{0}$, $E_{0}$, the kinetic energy. In my problem, the numerical mesh is quite fine as the frequency of the impinging wave is very high, thus I can't set a very large domain where the effects of the potential are negligible in the $\rho$ direction. In the full 2D problem I would be shooting the wave from the wall at $\rho_{min}$ at an angle of $\approx 89 ^{0}$ meaning that I would be still quite close to $z=0$ there.

Since the solution $\Psi$ will contain contributions from the impinging wave and the scattered wave respectively, written as $\Psi = \psi_{i}+\psi_{s}$, is there a way to modify the problem to involve two coupled pdes: one for the $\psi_{i}$, and one for the $\psi_{s}$ and leave the bcs for the plane wave and provide other bcs for the scattered one?

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood the problem. Do you mean you're solving for [tag:boundary-condition-at-infinity]? Can you show us the desired b.c. in traditional math notation?

Comment: @xzczd Sorry for being unclear. I have edited the post.

Comment: It's still unclear (at least for me). By "impinging wave" do you mean something amount to light source in Maxwell equation solving? If so, it should probably be introduced as an inhomogeneous term of equation rather than b.c., and at boundary you probably need things like ABC or PML to approximate open boundary. See e.g. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsFrequencyDomain.html Posts under [tag:boundary-condition-at-infinity] should also help.

Comment: @xzczd Apologies, I should have explained that. The impinging wave is a matter wave that is accounted for in the Schrodinger equation, its wave vector is $k =\sqrt(2m(E_{0}-V(z,\rho)$. I was talking about this wave's direction because that is making the problem awkward and not allowing me to approximate the wave vector far away from the potential. Thanks for the links, I will read those!